# Edit Form and populate data in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to edit form in same add form.
Below is my add-editcomponent.html where I want to populate data on clicking edit button and update the modified data.

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <form [formGroup]="createDimensionForm">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <label class="flex-col fw500 smCaps">Name* : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <input (blur)="onBlurSetDimension()" type="text" class="form-control"
               formControlName="dimensionName"/>
        <div `enter code here`
          *ngIf="createDimensionForm.controls['dimensionName'].invalid && (createDimensionForm.controls['dimensionName'].dirty || createDimensionForm.controls['dimensionName'].touched)">
          <div *ngIf="createDimensionForm.controls['dimensionName'].errors.required"
               style="color:red;">
            Name is required
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <label class="flex-col fw500 smCaps">Business Name : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <textarea type="textarea" rows="1" class="form-control"
                  name="description"
                  formControlName="description"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <label class="flex-col fw500 smCaps">Layer : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown">
            {{getValue('configLayerId')}}
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a *ngFor="let cf of configList"
               (click)="setValue('configLayerId',cf.layername)"
               class="dropdown-item">{{cf.layername}}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <label class="flex-col fw500 smCaps">File Format : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown">
            {{getValue('fileFormat')}}
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a *ngFor="let ff of fileformat"
               (click)="setValue('fileFormat',ff)"
               class="dropdown-item">{{ff}}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 pdt0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <table
            class="table table-bordered display table-sm col-sm-12 appTable">
            <thead>
            <th class="text-center" *ngFor="let head of dimTableHeader">
              {{head|titlecase}}
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngIf="refresh" formArrayName="fieldDetails">
            <tr *ngFor="let dim of dimensionColumn.controls ;let i=index;"
                [formGroupName]="i">
              <td style="word-break:break-all;"
                  *ngFor="let field of dimHeaders"
                  class="gmctd text-center">
                <div [ngSwitch]="field">
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'attributeName'">
                    <input (click)="onClickAttribute(i)"
                           (blur)="attrNameValidator(i)"
                           type="text"
                           formControlName="{{field}}"/>
                    <div *ngIf="dim.controls[field].invalid && (dim.controls[field].dirty || dim.controls[field].touched)">
                      <div *ngIf="dim.controls[field].errors.required"
                           style="color:red">
                        {{field}}
                        is
                        required.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'datatype'">
                    <select formControlName="{{field}}"
                            (change)="checkDatatypeCriteria($event, i)">
                      <option *ngFor="let op of datatype"
                              [ngValue]="op">
                        {{op}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'StartIndex'">
                    <input *ngIf="i == 0"
                           id="number"
                           class="width2"
                           type="number"
                           value="0"
                           min="0"
                           max="0"
                           onKeyUp="if(this.value>'0'){this.value='0';}"
                           formControlName="{{field}}"/>
                    <input *ngIf="i > 0"
                           id="number"
                           class="width2"
                           type="number"
                           value="1"
                           min="1"
                           max="9999999"
                           onKeyUp="if(this.value=='0'){this.value='null';}"
                           formControlName="{{field}}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'length'">
                    <input type="text"
                           class="width2"
                           formControlName="{{field}}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'primarykey'">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           (change)="getPrimaryStatus($event)"
                           formControlName="{{field}}">
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'partitionBy'">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           (change)="getPartitionStatus($event)"
                           formControlName="{{field}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="autocomplete" *ngSwitchCase="'dimension_select'">
                    <input list="dimension_select"
                           formControlName="{{field}}"
                           (keyup)="onclickdata($event,i)"
                           (change)="onSelectDimesnion($event,i)"/>
                    <datalist id="dimension_select">
                      <option *ngFor="let dimfil of dimensionNameList"
                              [ngValue]="dimfil.name">
                        {{dimfil.name}}
                      </option>
                    </datalist>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'dimension_column'">
                    <select
                      formControlName="{{field}}">
                      <option *ngFor="let col of dimensionFilterColumnObject[dimensionColumn.controls[i].value[this.dimHeaders[0]]]"
                              [ngValue]="col.COLUMN_NAME">
                        {{col.COLUMN_NAME}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchCase="'dimension_column2'" class="height-adjust">
                    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
                      (click)="checktemp()"
                      [placeholder]="'select'"
                      [data]="temp"
                      [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                      formControlName="{{field}}">
                    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                    <input (click)="onClickAttribute(i)"
                           (blur)="onBlurAttrbute(i)"
                           type="text"
                           formControlName="{{field}}"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Below is add-edit-component.ts

```js
export class adddimensionsComponent implements OnInit {
  dimHeaders = DimensionConstants.dimHiveHeaders;
  dimTableHeader = DimensionConstants.dimFixedWidthHeaders;

  createDimensionForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    dimensionName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/)]],
    description: [''],
    fieldDetails: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    schemaType: [''],
    fileFormat: ['Parquet'],
    configLayerId: ['', Validators.required],
    storage: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private gmcService: GMCService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,) {

    gmcService.getDimensions().subscribe(dimensions => {
      this.dimensionNameList = dimensions['dimensionData'];
      console.log(this.dimensionNameList)
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showAttribute = false;
    this.dimensionField = Array.from(this.fields);

    this.gmcService.getLayerByZone('Raw').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.configList = res['layerdata'];
      this.setValue('configLayerId', (this.configList.length > 0) ? this.configList[0].layername : null);
      this.setValue('fileFormat',this.getValue('fileFormat'))
    });
    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'id',
      textField: 'itemName',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true,
      maxHeight: 100
    };

    **this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const dimId = +params.get('dimensionId');
      if (dimId) {
        this.getSchemaDetail(dimId);
      }
    });**
  }

  **getSchemaDetail(dimId : number){
    this.gmcService.getAllDimensionDetails(dimId).subscribe((data : any) => {
      this.schemaData = data.schemaData
      console.log(this.schemaData)
    });
    this.createDimensionForm.patchValue({
      dimensionName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/)]],
      description: [''],
      fieldDetails: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      schemaType: [''],
      fileFormat: ['Parquet'],
      configLayerId: ['', Validators.required],
      storage: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }**

  onBlurSetDimension() {
    this.createDimensionForm.controls['fieldDetails'] = this.formBuilder.array([]),
      this.setDimensionColumn(this.dimensionField);
  }


    setDimensionColumn(fields) {
    const dim_Name = this.createDimensionForm.controls['dimensionName'].value;
    for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      const newobj = {};
      if (fields[i][this.dimHeaders[0]] !== '' && fields[i][this.dimHeaders[0]]) {
        newobj[this.dimHeaders[0]] = [fields[i][this.dimHeaders[0]], this.getValidator(this.dimHeaders[0])];
      } else {
        newobj[this.dimHeaders[0]] = [null, this.getValidator(this.dimHeaders[0])];

      }
      for (let j = 1; j < this.dimHeaders.length; j++) {
        const di = fields[i][this.dimHeaders[j]];
        newobj[this.dimHeaders[j]] = [di, this.getValidator(this.dimHeaders[j])];
      }
      this.dimensionColumn.push(this.formBuilder.group(newobj));
    }
  }

  get dimensionColumn() {
    return this.createDimensionForm.get('fieldDetails') as FormArray;
  }

  get isMasterValue() {
    return this.createDimensionForm.get('isMaster').value;
  }

  getValue(control) {
    return this.createDimensionForm.get(control).value;
  }

  setValue(control, value) {
    if (control === 'fileFormat') {
      console.log("inside set value")
      //this.getLayersByType(value);
      this.setDimensionHeaders(value);
      if (value == "MultiRecord") {
        console.log("isnde MultiRecord**********")
        this.showaddattr = true;
        this.cancel();
      } else {
        this.showaddattr = false;
      }
    }
    this.createDimensionForm.get(control).setValue(value);
  }

  addAttribute() {
    const ar = {
      'attributeName': '',
      'datatype': 'integer',
      'length': '20',
      'primarykey': '',
      'partitionby' : '',
      'dimension_select': null,
      'dimension_column': null
    };
    this.setDimensionColumn([ar]);
    this.dimensionField.push(ar);
  }

  
  submit() {
    const obj = Object.assign({}, this.createDimensionForm.value);
    console.log("before this.primcount");

    if (this.primCount > 0 && this.chekfixedwidthlength(obj['fieldDetails'])) {
      if (true && this.validName) {
        const obj = Object.assign({}, this.createDimensionForm.value);
        console.log(obj)
        const obj2 = Object.assign({}, this.dimensionColumn.value)
        obj['fieldDetails'] = this.dimensionColumn.value
        console.log(obj['fieldDetails'])
        this.extractMultiColumn(obj['fieldDetails'], obj.dimensionName);
        obj['schema_type'] = obj['storage']
        console.log(obj)
        this.gmcService.createDimension(obj).subscribe(res => {
          this.routeToList();
        }, (err) => {
        });
      }
    } 
  }

  routeToList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/GMC/dimensions/']);
  }
}
```

On adding new form, json will be as below :

```json
{
    "dimensionName": "newDim",
    "description": "",
    "fieldDetails": [
        {
            "attributeName": "Id",
            "datatype": "integer",
            "length": 20,
            "primarykey": true,
            "partitionBy": false,
            "StartIndex": 0,
            "dimension_column2": []
        },
        
    ],
    "schemaType": "",
    "fileFormat": "Parquet",
    "configLayerId": "azuerlayer",
    "storage": "",
    "schema_type": ""
}
```

On edit button click I am fetching data in below format:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 788,
        "name": "newDim",
        "description": "",
        "layername": "azuerlayer",
        "file_type": "Parquet",
        "attributename": "Id",
        "datatype": "integer",
        "length": 20,
        "primarykey": "Y",
        "partitionby": "N",
        "start_index": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 788,
        "name": "newDim",
        "description": "",
        "layername": "azuerlayer",
        "file_type": "Parquet",
        "attributename": "Name",
        "datatype": "varchar",
        "length": 20,
        "primarykey": "N",
        "partitionby": "N",
        "start_index": 0
    }
]
```

Data is coming from two tables. Now i want to populate the data while editing and save data in both the tables. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you are trying to fill the formGroup (createDimensionForm) with the data-set derived from your table? Then a simple .patchValue with an object that has keys corresponting to the names of the formcontrols in your formGroup and values corresponding to what you get from the data tables should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm entirely off base here, but if I understand correctly, you are trying to set the form values within the process of creating the form group, and the properties in your data object and your form controls share the same "keys"(for lack of a better word). If so, I might suggest that you modify your method to initialize the form group without setting any default values, and then, in the case of editing, iterate through each property in the to-be-updated object and populate the corresponding form control with its value using the formGroup.patchValue method

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your comment maybe be an answer and solve the OP issue, to transform it in a real and useful answer, it is better to copy and modify the code provided by the OP (ie, Nano Gupta); if not all "pieces" are there, you may comment at the question asking for details, or mix with some pseudocode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).